# Are there any Buffverse vampires in modern day who witnessed the crucifixion?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

In "School Hard" (the episode that introduced Spike) a vampire boasts of having witnessed the crucifixion.  Spike smacks him down (literally) and says "You were there? Oh, please! If every vampire who said he was at the Crucifixion was actually there, it would have been like Woodstock."  So lots of vampires make that boast, but are there any for whom the boast is true?

My impression is that most vampires relatively young, because they get killed by slayers or other vampires before learning enough to survive long-term.  Angelus and Spike are famous for their age and skills, and are less than 200 years old, and the oldest vampire we see for any length of time (as I recall) is the Master, who is definitely post-crucifixion (his pre-vampire name is (according to this [website](https://buffy.fandom.com/wiki/Master)) Heinrich Joseph Nest, a name that is no earlier than medieval).

Are there any canonical vampires in the Buffyverse who were turned before 33 AD?

Comment: The oldest I saw was supposed to be Dracula who was post crucifixion.

Comment: The Master, Kakistos and Prince of Lies are all ancient, more than a thousand years old, but I don't think we've got a defined age on either of the latter two.

Comment: Can you explain why you say the master’s previous name is no earlier than medieval? Certainly it’s not the Joseph part

Comment: Combining a Germanic name with a Hebrew name makes it a name that someone would have only after Christianity reached the Germans.  In addition, having a last name in Germany is something that started after 1000 AD

Comment: Ok. It’s not possible that it was originally a Hebrew name that was later germanicised?

Comment: There is no known vampire older than the Master, as your link notes and cites to _Prophecy Girl_.

Comment: Was the crucifixion held at night?

Comment: @OrangeDog: Ah - I didn't spot that in my link.  What to make the the answer?

Comment: @Andrew "No", but with maybe the quote from the episode, and a possible consideration of the Prince of Lies (who was dead by then)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Love it, but Matthew, Mark, and Luke all mention that the sky [darkened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crucifixion_darkness) from noon on during the Crucifixion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We don't know of any vampires that actually witnessed the crucifixion. As Spike says, this is a common boast, but not one that anyone's really able to back up.

At the very least though, we do encounter a vampire that appears in Buffy that is old enough to have potentially done so, [***Kakistos***](https://buffy.fandom.com/wiki/Kakistos), who makes an appearance in [*BtVS: Faith, Hope and Trick*](https://buffy.fandom.com/wiki/Faith,_Hope_%26_Trick)

[image]

He's described in the episode by Giles thusly;

> "'Kakistos' is Greek. It means the worst of the worst. It's also the name of a vampire **so old that his hands and feet are cloven**.

and in *[Go Ask Malice: A Slayer's Diary](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/293363)* Faith's watcher Diana Dormer advises us that his origins aren't just in Greece, but ***ancient*** Greece, a period that someone as educated as Professor Dormer would be aware ranged from approximately the 8th to the 6th Century B.C., well before the life (and death) of Jesus.

> She had asked me (innocently, I thought at the time) if I knew
> anything about maenads, and I told her what I knew, that they were
> identified in Greek mythology as the followers of Bacchus, also known
> as the Bakkhai.
>
> According to Weiron’s Codex, **the maenads were the slaves of a vampire
> in ancient Greece known as Kakistos**, or the Worst of the Worst; the
> legend is that he would have his slaves refer to him as Father. These
> women were villagers who would be abducted and—through a combination
> of torture, sleep, and food deprivation, and perhaps
> magick—subsequently transformed into soldiers in a frenzied,
> bloodthirsty army, each willing to die for him. The interesting bit is
> that they were not sired but rather remained human—indeed, they even
> bore a brand, common to human slaves at the time.

Comment: Given that elderly vampires become misshapen, it's certainly possible that [Prince of Lies](https://buffy.fandom.com/wiki/Prince_of_Lies) is also old enough to predate 0 B.C., we just don't know for certain.